# Print Unicode Character Android TextView

Tags: java, android, unicode, textview, char

I am trying to use emoji icons listed here

http://apps.timwhitlock.info/emoji/tables/unicode#block-6a-missing-emoticons

Each icon has a unicode character with it like

U+1F601 is the Unicode of "GRINNING FACE WITH SMILING EYES" =

My question here is how can i set this unicode character in textview.

I cannot create a char from this value as it will require only four hexadecimal values.

For example i created a char like this

```
char c = '\u27A1';
```

This c works great if i append that to textview and shows me the image properly.
How can i create a char of Unicode value U+1F601 - Bytes UTF-8 \xF0\x9F\x98\x81

Also there are certain unicode characters with double values like this 
U+1F1F7 U+1F1FA = Bytes UTF-8 \xF0\x9F\x87\xB7\xF0\x9F\x87\xBA

How can i display them all in textview ?

Comment: This guy has done a nice piece of work out there. [Emojicon] - https://github.com/rockerhieu/emojicon

Answer (score 5):

UTF-8 \xF0\x9F\x87\xB7\xF0\x9F\x87\xBA it is a UTF8 Format you have to make it in UTF16 format for these charectr.

Simply print the UTF16 format 
String c="\uD83D\uDE01";

now show the c string in text view.